# connect: Network is unreachable - but connection is actually there

Tags: networking, wireless

Lately my Dell XPS 15 does some strange things.
It is connected to the internet as I can load all my sites just fine.
Only thing is that I can not SSH to the outside of any network, neither can I ping outside my network.

It always displays

```
connect: Network is unreachable.
```

For some reason I can not enter askubuntu.com via my laptop. It always says `ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE`

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, latest updates installed. Connected via Wlan.

Please tell me which further information are needed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason no gateway was added to my routes. I ran the following command:

```
sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 wlan0
```

It's working all fine now :)